# transfer data in functions ? Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i transfer certain data in function like `test()`;

I saw some people did this like putting the data in the brackets like test(data);

When the function executes it will use the data
 for example:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
  test(somedata);
});

function text();{
//how can i get the data stored
}
```

am i doing it right? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: This: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-intro/0#!/exercise/0

Comment: This is called a function parameter. You may find it easier to read up on basic programming concepts before you try harder tasks.

Comment: Passing parameters to functions creates variables with scope local to those functions.  Scope is very fundamental and is critical in understanding the value behind object oriented programming and name spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the parameter/argument to the `test()` function.

```
$('#element').click(function(){
  test(somedata);
});

function test(arg1){
   alert(arg1);
}
```

Take a look at [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) MDN document.